# Не правильно выводятся элементы ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Необходимо вывести все элементы, которые встречаются один раз в списке. У меня же один раз выводится совершенно другие элементы. Как мне это исправить?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zadanie2 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Razmer spiska: ");
        //int n  = scanner.nextInt();
        int k = 1, x = 0;
        ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.print("Spisok: ");
        array1.add("Tom");
        array1.add("Alice");
        array1.add("Tom");
        array1.add("Sam");
        array1.add("Kate");
        array1.add("Sam");
        array1.add("Bob");
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++)
        {
            String str = array1.get(i);
            for(int j = 1; j < array1.size(); j++)
            {
                for(int z = 0; z < array2.size(); z++)
                    {
                    if((str.equals(array1.get(j)) == true) && (str.equals(array2.get(z)) == false))
                    {
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(k == 1)
            {
                array2.add(str);
            }
            k = 0;
        }
        
        for(String count : array2)
        {
            System.out.print(count + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Выводит: "Spisok: Tom Kate", а должен "Spisok: Alice Kate Bob"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что для решения данной достаточно простой задачи вы написали такой код, который даже сами не смогли разобрать и отдебажить... Посему ответ на вопрос "как это исправить" - пишите код проще и короче, тогда таких ошибок либо не будет, либо их легко будет найти.
Например, так:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Zadanie2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        int desiredNumberRepetitions = 1;
        
        List<String> sourceList = Stream.of("Tom", "Alice", "Tom", "Sam", "Kate", "Sam", "Bob")
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // создаем коллекцию с исходными данными
        
        List<String> result = sourceList.stream() //создаем стрим из нашей исходной коллекции
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) //получаем коллекцию MAP где ключ - элемент, значение - количество его повторений
                .entrySet().stream() //создаем стрим из полученной на предыдущем шаге MAP
                .filter(e->e.getValue()==desiredNumberRepetitions) // фильтруем все имена, которые встречаются не один раз
                .map(e->e.getKey()) //преобразуем стрим entrySet в стрим String
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //получаем коллекцию имен, повторяющихся 1 раз
        
        System.out.println("Size of list : " + sourceList.size());
        System.out.println("List : " + result);
        
    }
```

Comment: Крайне тяжелый вариант тоже :)

Comment: Да перечитал требования, тогда ваш вариант отлично подходит.

Comment: А где про данные методы почитать можно? Сколько искал информацию для решения задачи - только equals всплывал.

Comment: @zxc_firebird читайте про stream api , не ошибетесь)